# Add frame ancestor / no error / but still can't display iframe

Tags: iframe, x-frame-options, ancestor

I try to open in iframe a webiste : narbonne-tourisme.com from my website api.opentlv.com

We add the frame ancestor header but it still don't work :

Did you see something we forgot to change here :
[image]

[image]

```
Refused to frame 'https://www.narbonne-tourisme.com/' because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors 'self' api.opentlv.com 51.15.190.144".
```

Thanks by advance,

Answer (score 0):

The answer was : I was missing http/https

[image]